# How can I set a dynamic Result Set in Classic Report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am creating a process to import a CSV File and display it in Classic Report.
That process uses PL/SQL, it has validation checks and edit some string data.

I want to set the processed Result Set named `CSV_RESULT_EDITED` to the Source of Classic Report named `P14_Report`.
Is it possible to write it like the text below this?

> P14_Report.Source = CSV_RESULT_EDITED

Thank you to see my question :)

Comment: The source of a report query is a select statement, not a resultset. Have a look at the apex_collections api, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle a dynamic resultset in an apex application is by using the [apex_collections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/APEX_COLLECTION.html#GUID-859B488C-2628-44D7-969F-50872C685B76) api. Add all the rows to the collection when processing the imported data and then in the report source you'd have something like:

```
  SELECT <relevant columns for your use case> 
    FROM apex_collections 
   WHERE collection_name = '<your_collection_name>'
```

The collection data will be persistent as long as the apexe session is active

Comment: Oh, Thank you! But wait ... I'm starting to read apex_collections document.

Comment: I got it! I got it!!!! Thank you a lot!! I see the Report as I had hoped :D